# How to make asynchronous call with timeout

Tags: c++, asynchronous, timeout, boost-asio

I want to make an asynchronous call in C++ with timeout, meaning I want to achieve sth like that.

```
AsynchronousCall(function, time);
if(success)
    //call finished succesfully
else
    //function was not finished because of timeout
```

EDIT : Where function is a method that takes a lot of time and I want to interrupt it when it takes too much time.
I' ve been looking for how to achieve it and I thinki `boost::asio::deadline_timer` is way to go. I guess calling `timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&A::fun, this, args))` is what I need, but I do not know how to find if the call was success or was aborted due to timeout.

EDIT: after the answer from ForEveR my code now looks like this.

```
    boost::asio::io_service service;
boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(service);
timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&A::CheckTimer, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
boost::thread bt(&A::AsynchronousMethod, this, timer, args);  //asynchronous launch

void A::CheckTimer(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
{
    cout<<"ok"<<endl;
}
// timer is cancelled.
else
{
    cout<<"error"<<endl;
}
}
```

I wanted to pass the timer by reference and cancel it in the end of asynchronous method, but I got an error that I cannot access private member declared in class ::boost::asio::basic_io_object.

Maybe using the deadline timer is not that good idea ? I would really appreciate any help. I am passing the timer to the function, because the method that calls the asynchronous method is asynchronous itself and thus I cannot have one timer for whole class or sth like that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [boost::asio::placeholders::error](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/placeholders__error.html)

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(
&A::fun, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));

A::fun(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
   // timeout, or some other shit happens
   if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
   {
   }
   // timer is cancelled.
   else
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: I included boost/asio/placeholders.hpp and still I cant find the boost::asio::placeholders::error :/ also the main job the `fun` function does, should be in the begining of the function?

Comment: @cygi1989 ehm... fun is simply timer callback. What work it does, regardless of errors? If you cannot find placeholders::error, try to use simply _1.

Comment: Ok, so maybe I missunderstood the usage of deadline_timer. I want to call a function A::fun asynchronously. This function does a lot of job, and I want to interrupt this function if it takes too much time.

Comment: @cygi1989 set timer and then call this function asynchronously. After executing of function (in the end of function probably) call `timer.cancel()`, then handler will be executed with `operation_aborted` signal and will be executed with `success`, if timeout happends. However, `boost::asio` is not for async work, it's for some internet work.

Comment: I edited the question, but still doesn't know how it should work.

Comment: @cygi1989 if you want pass timer by reference - you should use `boost::ref`